# What aspects of Soviet life were not controlled by Stalin?

Tags: 20th-century, soviet-union, stalin

Stalinism controlled social life through propaganda, political life through the use of political crime and the politicization of life and the workers life, with proletarianism dominating all aspects of work and more.

I can't seem to find any aspects of Soviet life that Stalinism didn't control. What were the limits of Stalin's control?

Comment: I'm waiting for @anixx to weigh-in on this as the [Mighty Eagle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stxIgU7xdSA) perhaps also would :)

Comment: Are you seeking to learn about some kind of opposition to Stalin and Communist ideology?

Comment: Please include in your question, on what basis you tell the difference between "did" and "didn't". Without it it's difficult to understand what answer you expect.

Comment: I'm still tangled up in how many negatives. Is there no evidence that not Stalin didn't control not life?   Could you rephrase the question so that it is clearer what you're looking for.   What is an "aspect of Soviet life"? (which trouser leg you put on first?)   You seem to be asking what were the limits of Stalin's control, and I'm not convinced that there is a simple answer to that question.

Comment: Do you consider a street patroled by law enforcement to be under control of Stalinism?

Comment: Don't worry I've got answers now, I was looking for things like religion, and how it still thrived despite Stalin's attempts to stop it.

Comment: @OllyPrice if you have answers that seem sufficient, then why don't you write an answer to your own question (you can do that) and consider updating the question to be more clear?

Answer (score 7):

The main historiography, which you should really have searched prior to asking the question.  Most obviously Sheila Fitzpatrick's work on everyday Stalinism at the work unit level, particularly *Everyday Stalinism: Ordinary Life in Extraordinary Times* (1999).  Rossman (2005) *Worker resistance under Stalin*.  Andrle (1988) *Workers in Stalin's Russia*.

Answer (score 7):

The state and Communist party TRIED to control ALL aspects of people's life. Another question is how successful they were.

Answer (score 0):

One small example of radio in fighter jets.
Soviet fighters received radio in the mid-30's. But the radio was bad and heavy. The pilots shot out the radio.
The command of the Red Army three times wrote the order "Use the radio!". Result? In 1941 Soviet pilots flew without radio. Where is the fear of Stalin?
Stalin controlled everything? This is a fairytale.

Comment: All soviet pilots did this?

Comment: Of course not. If normal commander - all the pilots with walkie-talkies.
Most often "saved weight" pilots of fighters.
My grandfather was a Pe-2 and A-20 pilot. He told a lot of interesting data.
For example, he told that the aircraft were standing exactly in one line. It is beautiful. Russian commanders loved beauty. As a result, the Luftwaffe was bombed by beautiful targets. Stupidity of commanders? Yes.

Comment: Alas, there were no other officers. It was a peasant country. All literate people are young people. Germany is an excellent military tradition and responsibility. Russia quickly forgets good traditions and loves parades. And responsibility in Russia was only under Stalin.